# Opening my application when a USB device is inserted on Windows using WMI

Tags: .net, wmi

I'm trying to launch an event when someone plugs in a USB device.  For now, I'm content to simply print something to the console (in the finished product, it will launch an application).

This code is very loosely adapted from: https://serverfault.com/questions/115496/use-wmi-to-detect-a-usb-drive-was-connected-regardless-of-whether-it-was-mounted

There are two problems:
1) I need to pass the argument to Management scope dynamically because this will be installed on computers I don't use or whose name I don't know.  2) I'm getting an invalid namespace exception when I call w.Start();

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
static ManagementEventWatcher w=null;
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddInstUSBHandler();
        for(;;);
    }

public static void USBRemoved(object sneder, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A USB device inserted");
    }


 static void AddInstUSBHandler()
    {
        WqlEventQuery q;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("HQ\\DEV1");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges=true;

            q=new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName+="_InstanceCreationEvent";
            q.WithinInterval=new TimeSpan(0,0,3);
            q.Condition=@"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
            w=new ManagementEventWatcher(scope,q);
            w.EventArrived+=new EventArrivedEventHandler(USBRemoved);
            w.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect -> "HQ\DEV1"

```
//ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("HQ\\DEV1");
```

Follow [ManagementScope Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx)

```
    // Make a connection to a remote computer.
    // Replace the "FullComputerName" section of the
    // string "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2" with
    // the full computer name or IP address of the
    // remote computer.
    ManagementScope scope = 
        new ManagementScope(
        "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2");
```

Comment: I added the full computer name--and then got "invalid class".  If I change it to \\\\HQ\\DEV1\\root\\cimv2, (which isn't the full computer name but the path in the domain) I get "access is denied."  Would that be because I'm not the administrator on my box?

Comment: I would say so.  I have been having similar problems.  If you go to Computer Management -> Services and Applications -> WMI Control then you or your system adim can set the permissions.  I have done this on both windows 7 and xp but I can only get access on xp.